# How to select unique entries from multiple text files and print in output file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, command-line

I have 3 files with similar data. I want a bash script which can read the 3 files and output the unique entries with their values. Example:

```
1.txt
aceE    14
aceF    8
adhE    20
asnS    2
carB    2
dnaK    3
eno     2

2.txt
aceE    11
aceF    7
acnB    2
acrB    1
adhE    22
asnS    2
dapD    3

3.txt
aceE    16
aceF    10
adhE    18
aroK    2
asnS    3
dapD    4
dnaK    4
```

So the output should look like:

```
acnB    2
acrB    1
aroK    2
carB    2
eno     2
```

Comment: So far I have: __( cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt ) | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1==1 {print $2}'__. But this only gives me the names of the unique entries, not the corresponding values.

Comment: the field separator is a tab o are them pretty print files?

Comment: yes, it's a tab

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `uniq` or compatible (for the `-w` option):

```
sort {1,2,3}.txt | uniq -u -w5
acnB    2
acrB    1
aroK    2
carB    2
eno     2
```

edit: to be a bit more flexible with the lengths of the first field, some of guillermo's approach could be implemented.

```
grep -f <(sort {1,2,3}.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq -u) <(sort {1,2,3}.txt)
```

As it turns out, the delimiter in the input files are `<tab>` and not `<space>`. This got changed by pasting the input files into the question. :-(
Nevertheless this should work with `<tab>`.

```
grep -f <(sort {1,2,3}.txt | cut -f1 | uniq -u) <(sort {1,2,3}.txt)
```

Comment: unfortunately this gives the same output as @guillermo 's original solution. I don't know if my OS or bash is being an issue here

Answer (score 1):

I propose this:

```
sort {1,2,3}.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq -u | xargs -I '{}' grep -h "{}" {1,2,3}.txt
```

---

Sort the contents of the files:

```
sort {1,2,3}.txt
```

---

Output just the first column:

```
cut -d' ' -f1
```

---

Filter uniques:

```
uniq -u

acnB
acrB
aroK
carB
eno
```

---

With the output feed `grep`:

```
xargs -I '{}' grep -h "{}" {1,2,3}.txt

acnB    2
acrB    1
aroK    2
carB    2
eno     2
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105406/discussion-on-answer-by-guillermo-chamorro-how-to-select-unique-entries-from-mul).

Comment: Please don't continue the discussion here. Take it to the chat room and, once you've figured out the details, you can modify your answer to include them.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  n[$1]++ {delete s[$1]; next}
  {s[$1] = $0}
  END {for (i in s) print s[i]}' [123].txt
```

Comment: Thanks Stéphane. This works.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two hashes, `%H`  will keep track if the key (first field `$F[0])` has been encountered or seen before. If yes, then we stuff an `undef` value for this key in the hash `%h`. OTW, the line `$_` is stuffed. At the end of record readin phase, aka, eof, we simply publish the values of the hash `%h`.

```
% perl -ane '@F and $h{$F[0]} = $H{$F[0]}++ ? undef : $_}{print values %h' 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

**output**:

```
carB    2
acnB    2
aroK    2
acrB    1
eno     2
```

Comment: I initially tried something like this. But similar to @guillermo chamorro 's solution, the output shows all entries from all files. Do you think it's because the value for each entry is different in different files? Example: if all the files have adhE but the values for adhE are 2, 4, and 6 in different files, all the three might be recognized as unique?

Comment: Post real data sample to see what's going on. Bcoz we ran on the input you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --csv --fs "\t" -N count-similar -g 1 then filter '$count==1' then cut -x -f count 1.txt  2.txt 3.txt
```

you will have

```
carB    2
eno     2
acnB    2
acrB    1
aroK    2
```